# Wrong date with moment JS plugins

Tags: momentjs

Trying to generate 15 days advance date using moment JS but it doesnt starts with today's date but the day before.

```
 console.log( "Today's date : " + d1.getDate().toString())
            for (i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
                console.log(moment(d1).day(i, 'd').format('MM/DD/YYYY') )
                selectDt.append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", moment(d1).day(i,'d').format('MM/DD/YYYY'))
                    .text(moment(d1).day(i,'d').format('MMM-DD,YYYY'))
                    .prop("selected", (selval != undefined) ? (moment(d1).day(i,'d').format('MMM-DD,YYYY') == selval) : '')
            )
        }
```

Result is,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to use the moment `add` method for getting after 15 dates. If you want before 15 use the moment `subtract` method.

For your code with my changes.

```
console.log( "Today's date : " + d1.getDate().toString())
for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    console.log(moment(d1).add(i, 'd').format('MM/DD/YYYY') )
    selectDt.append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", moment(d1).add(i,'d').format('MM/DD/YYYY'))
        .text(moment(d1).add(i,'d').format('MMM-DD,YYYY'))
        .prop("selected", (selval != undefined) ? (moment(d1).day(i,'d').format('MMM-DD,YYYY') == selval) : '')
    )
}
```

My working code

```
var d1 = new Date();
console.log( "Today's date : " + d1.getDate().toString())
for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    console.log(moment(d1).add(i, 'day').format('MM/DD/YYYY') )
}
```

My Output

[image]